# SQL - how do I return the number of failed orders if there is a condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So, I have two tables - table customers and table orders. 
`customer with attributes custid, name, address` and `orders with attributes customerid, orderid, date and status`. I need to return the ids of those customers, who have had more than 15% of their orders with status "failed".

This is what I have written and does not currently work:

```
SELECT C.custid
FROM customers C
WHERE C.custid IN (SELECT O.customerid, COUNT(status)
                   FROM orders O
                   WHERE O.status='failed'
                   GROUP BY O.custid
                   HAVING COUNT(status)=0.15)
```

Comment: Let the sub-query return O.customerid only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach using aggregation on the `orders` table:

```
SELECT customterid
FROM orders
GROUP BY customerid
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'failed' THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*) > 0.15;
```

Comment: thank you, Tim, it looks like I was thinking way too complicated!

Comment: In Postgres, it is simpler to write:  `HAVING AVG( (status = 'failed')::int ) > 0.15`.